# Filtragem de resultados em PostgreSQL a partir de menor valor de apenas uma coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

É uma questão de lógica e conhecimento dos recursos do PostgreSQL. Tenho o seguinte resultado de uma consulta:

[image: resultado da query]

Preciso fazer uma filtragem, agrupando por [hora] de modo que permaneça apenas a [hora_real] mais próxima e, consequentemente, toda a linha correspondente (tenho uma série de outras colunas).

Comecei a tentar solucionar calculando o valor absoluto da diferença em segundos. Entretanto, agrupando por hora e calculando o  valor mínimo da coluna [dif_abs], como garantir que os outros valores da linha correspondente permaneçam? Visto que não posso utilizar um agregador, pois poderia não corresponder em alguns casos.

Comment: Nesse caso, deveria permanecer apenas a linha com dif_abs 45? Coloque o resultado esperado e com mais valores, se possível.

Comment: Murillo, consegui com DISTINCT ON. Vou postar a resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com DISTINCT ON.

Em [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/)
, vi uma solução pra isso.

Posso ordenar por [hora] e [dif_abs] e extrair a primeira linha distinta pelo id (que não está na tabela exemplo que mostrei, mas tenho na minha consulta; ou mesmo podemos criar com `row_number() OVER ()`). Assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_hora) id_hora, hora, hora_real, dif_abs FROM qry 
ORDER BY id_hora ASC, dif_abs ASC
```

Dessa forma, terei a primeira linha com id único em que a [hora_real] é mais próxima da [hora].